# C5.0 returns tree of size 1

Tags: r, machine-learning, finance, decision-tree

I'm working with LendingClub's publicly available data on approved loans from 2012-2015: https://www.lendingclub.com/info/download-data.action

What it looks like

[image]

```
library(C50)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#Preprocessed in terminal with 'tail -n +2 LoanStats3c.csv > approved.csv'
setwd("~/Dropbox/dataprojects/Lending Club/")
approval <- read.csv("approved.csv")
approved_2014 <- read.csv("approved_2014.csv")
approved_2013 <- read.csv("approved_2013.csv")

#Create a big dataframe
approved <- rbind(approval, approved_2014, approved_2013)
#Filter it
approved <- filter(approved, application_type == "INDIVIDUAL", purpose=="debt_consolidation")
keep <- c("loan_status","addr_state", "annual_inc", "delinq_2yrs", "dti", "grade","sub_grade", "home_ownership", "emp_length", "loan_amnt", "installment", "int_rate", "open_acc", "zip_code", "inq_last_6mths", "verification_status", "pub_rec", "term", "revol_bal", "revol_util")
approved <- approved[keep]
#Scramble it
set.seed(12345)
approved <- approved[order(runif(429949)), ]
#Drop Unused Levels -- necessary for C5.0
approved <- droplevels(approved)

num_examples = dim(approved)[1]

#Prepares class variables.
approved$loan_status <- as.character(approved$loan_status)
approved$loan_status[approved$loan_status=="Charged Off"] <- "0"
approved$loan_status[approved$loan_status=="Default"] <- "0"
approved$loan_status[approved$loan_status=="Late (31-120 days)"] <- "0"
approved$loan_status[approved$loan_status=="Current"] <- "1"
approved$loan_status[approved$loan_status=="Fully Paid"] <- "1"
approved$loan_status[approved$loan_status=="Issued"] <- "1"
approved$loan_status[approved$loan_status=="In Grace Period"] <- "1"
approved$loan_status[approved$loan_status=="Late (16-30 days)"] <- "1"
approved$loan_status[approved$loan_status==""] <- "missing"
approved$loan_status <- as.factor(approved$loan_status)
summary(approved$loan_status)

#Change these to numerics so they can be normalized
approved$int_rate <- as.numeric(sub("%", "", approved$int_rate))
approved$revol_util <- as.numeric(sub("%", "", approved$revol_util))
approved$term <- as.numeric(sub("months", "", approved$term))

#Normalize Numeric Columns
ind <- sapply(approved, is.numeric)
approved[ind] <- lapply(approved[ind], scale)
levels(approved)[levels(approved) == ""] <- "missing"

#Create Train/Test Split
split_pt2 = ceiling(num_examples*0.7) 
split_pt1 = floor(num_examples*0.7)
approved_train <- approved[1:split_pt1,]
approved_test <- approved[split_pt2:num_examples,]

train_class <- approved_train$loan_status
test_class <- approved_test$loan_status
#Remove the class from the training/testing data
approved_train <- approved_train[,2:20]
approved_test <- approved_test[,2:20]


m <- C5.0(approved_train, train_class, trials=10)
summary(m)
p <- predict(m, approved_test)
summary(p)
```

I'm new to R & C5.0, so I might be overlooking something very obvious. Not sure whats wrong here. Thanks for any insight you can provide.

```
Call:
C5.0.default(x = approved_train, y = train_class, trials = 10)


C5.0 [Release 2.07 GPL Edition]     Tue Nov 24 16:38:41 2015
-------------------------------

Class specified by attribute `outcome'

Read 128985 cases (20 attributes) from undefined.data

-----  Trial 0:  -----

Decision tree:
 1 (128985/8250)

-----  Trial 1:  -----

Decision tree:
 1 (128985/36371.2)

*** boosting reduced to 1 trial since last classifier is very inaccurate

*** boosting abandoned (too few classifiers)


Evaluation on training data (128985 cases):

        Decision Tree   
      ----------------  
      Size      Errors  

         1 8250( 6.4%)   <<


        (a)    (b)    <-classified as
      -----  -----
              8250    (a): class 0
            120735    (b): class 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that the reason is that none of the predictors are not strong enough to create a decision branch. Keep in mind that the loans in your data set were already screened by Lending Club. If any of them were likely to default, Lending Club would not offer them.

Here is an example with NO relationship between `class` and `x1` and `x2`. As expected, `C5.0` returns decision tree size 1.

```
library(C50)  
data <- data.frame(y=runif(50), x1=runif(50), x2=runif(50))
class <- as.factor(ifelse(data$y<0.5,"yes","no"))
tree <- C5.0(data[,-1],class) 
tree
## Tree size: 1
```

Here is an example where there IS a relationship between `class` and `x1`. As expected, `C5.0` returns decision tree size 2.

```
class <- as.factor(ifelse(data$x1<0.5,"yes","no"))
tree <- C5.0(data[,-1],class) 
tree
## Tree size: 2
```